# Stock quote discrepancy from historical charts

Tags: stocks

I owned a stock back in 2018 and my broker listed the price around 11 bucks.  If I look at the charts, it quotes it at well over a 100 for the same date.

Comment: Where there any splits since then?

Comment: Supply the stock symbol so that it can be checked.